JHipster Lite - Can JHipster Lite use JHipster Domain Language (JDL)?
Can I use JDL or something else to define entities within JHipster Lite? Or is that only for JHipster?
Is there any documentation related to this? I think it would be useful to add this to the JHipster documentation because it's not clear.
I've been looking at the official site and the links below.
https://www.jhipster.tech/jhipster-lite/
JHipster Lite Landscape
https://lite.jhipster.tech/landscape
JHipster Domain Language (JDL) Studio:
https://start.jhipster.tech/jdl-studio/

You can't use JDL on Jhipster-lite. Here is the link for a detailed explanation.
PS: if it answer your question, please, mark it as correct answer.
Thanks !
